# Mathematical term for $W(x,y,z) = f(x)*\frac{1}{111} + g(x,y)*\frac{10}{111} + h(x,y,z)*\frac{100}{111}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, terminology

Assume I have the words A, B and C.
In my calculation, occurrences of ABC should have much bigger weight than AB, and occurrences of AB should be much bigger than A.

$W(x,y,z) = P(x)*\frac{1}{111} + P(x,y)*\frac{10}{111} + P(x,y,z)*\frac{100}{111}$

and I apply the context = $\{A, B, C\}$ to function $W$.

$P(x,y)$ means : (number of xy used together) / (count of bigrams)

My question is not about the formula itself, because I have already implemented a much more complicated form of it. However, I cannot write a proper documentation about it. I don't know the math term.

Is there a mathematical term for what $W$ is doing?

"increasing-size-increasing-weight-summing" ?

Comment: "Weighted average".

Comment: Yes, it is weighted average. However isn't there a special name for that when the number of parameters are increasing?
I would say P(x), P(x,y) and P(x,y,z) doesn't have the same class.
To me weighted average is more like $P(x)*k + P(y)*l + P(z)*m$